# TestNg + Spring Integration how to abstract beforeMethod

Tags: java, spring, testng

In JUnit spring integration we can extend all the test classes to an abstract class to have `@Before` implementation in one place.

But in TestNG since we have to extend all test classes to `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` we will not be able to extend to an abstract class. Any idea how to have an abstract class with `@BeforeMethod`, `@AfterMethod` in TestNG with Spring?

Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

First build a class that will house your custom @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod annotated methods as below :

```
public class LocalSpringBase extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.err.println("Another beforeMethod");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        System.err.println("Another afterMethod");
    }

}
```

You then have your actual test class extend your LocalSpringBase as shown below :

```
@ContextConfiguration (locations = {"classpath:spring-test-config.xml"})
public class TestSpring extends LocalSpringBase {

    @Autowired
    EmailGenerator emailGenerator;

    @Test ()
    void testEmailGenerator() {
        String email = emailGenerator.generate();
        System.out.println(email);

        Assert.assertNotNull(email);
        Assert.assertEquals(email, "feedback@yoursite.com");
    }

}
```

Including the rest of the classes also for the sake of completeness
The interface

```
public interface EmailGenerator {
    String generate();
}
```

A concrete implementation

```
@Service
public class RandomEmailGenerator implements EmailGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generate() {
        return "feedback@yoursite.com";
    }
}
```

The examples have been borrowed from [www.mkyong.com/](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually just working on this. I chose to do this using a listener. Why use a listener rather than extending? Because Java only provides inheritance of a single class, and I don't want the limitation on my framework.

In my example, I was experimenting with abstracting the initMocks call for initializing mocks before executing each test method for a Mockito test

Here is my Listener:

```
public class MockDemoListener implements ITestListener {

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(result.getInstance());
    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here is my Test class:

```
public class MockTest1 {

    @Mock
    private DemoObj mockObj1;

    private DemoObj prevObj;

    @Test
    public void testMockIsInitialized() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mockObj1);
        prevObj = mockObj1;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockIsReInitialized() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(mockObj1);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(mockObj1, prevObj);
    }
}
```

And here is my Mockito xml suite:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="suite1">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.demo.listener.MockDemoListener" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="mockTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.demo.test.MockTest1"/>
            <class name="com.demo.test.MockTest1"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I just want to note that you can also specify Listeners for classes by adding the @Listeners annotation to the top of the class.

I also want to note this is not a good convention for constructing tests in practice, but for the purposes of my experimenting to ensure the mocks are reset before the invocation of a new test, it is fine here.